# Which Python Forecasting method should I use

Tags: python, machine-learning, forecasting

I want to forecast upcoming total users on a daily basis within Python using a machine learning algorithm. Check the pattern below:
[image]

Looking at this graph, I was wondering if someone knows which forecasting method in Python I should use to predict?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems too broad, and possibly off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

If you have no additional data expect the user data over time which you have shown, the only thing you can do is try to find a function dependent on time which gives you a good approximation for that plot (ordinary curve fitting). I suppose that's not what you want. 
To do a predection (which can be done not only by a machine learning approach), you need other data which is somehow correlated to the data you want to predict.